# Android support compat errors

Tags: android, android-studio, compilation

My project worked fine last time.

Now I can't build this, I see a lot of problems in com.android.support/apcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v21/values.xml

```
 Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

I need to build my application for minSdkVersion 16 and targetVersion 16.

My project is compiling only if I set minSdkVersion, targetVersion and compilingVersion to 21.

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2.

[image]

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see a lot of problems in com.android.support/apcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v21/values.xml

Your `compileSdkVersion` should be 22, if you are going to use a `22.x.y` version of a support library.

> I need to build my application for minSdkVersion 16 and targetVersion 16.

Set `minSdkVersion` to 16, `targetSdkVersion` to 16, and `compileSdkVersion` to 22. Changing `minSdkVersion` nor `targetSdkVersion` values will not result in errors like the one that you cite.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you need to use:

**compileSdkVersion 21**

I didn't known before about:

*compileSdkVersion* - is the version of the API the app is compiled against. This means you can use Android API features included in that version of the API.

*minSdkVersion* - controls the lowest level you say your application can run on.

*targetSdkVersion* - ontrols any automatically applied backward compatibility features